# How to make field enum migration yii2

Tags: yii, enums, yii2, migration, data-migration

I make field ENUM and the result is error when I use `yii migrate/up` on CMD windows.

```
public function up()
{
    $tableOptions = null;
    if ($this->db->driverName === 'mysql') {
        $tableOptions = 'CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE=InnoDB';
    }

    $this->createTable('{{%user_social_media}}', [
        'social_media' => $this->ENUM('facebook', 'google', 'twitter', 'github'),
        'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
        'username' => $this->string(),
        'user_id' => $this->integer(11),
        'created_at' => $this->integer(11),
        'updated_at' => $this->integer(11),            
       ], $tableOptions);
}
```

[image: When I migrate/up error]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is no enum() method at the moment since not every DB is supporting ENUM fields. You can do it manually though:

```
'social_media' => "ENUM('facebook', 'google', 'twitter', 'github')",
```

Note:
This solution is for Mysql only

For related Postgresql content visit [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-enum.html)

Comment: an open discussion about it just in case it changes in future: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/9797

Comment: hi @bizley this will work for only mysql db, right? I have tried in pgsql but didn't worked

Comment: @SohelAhmedM yes, this is for MySQL but quick google search gave me this https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/datatype-enum.html so it's just a matter of implementing that statement into migration.

Comment: i am adding a note

Answer (score 1):

Actually the best way of working this and keeping your migrations clean would be by using some tool/helper like the one provided by the yii2mod team https://github.com/yii2mod/yii2-enum

this way you can build the enum functionality on code, works like a charm.

i.e. an enum for genderType

```
<?php

namespace common\models\enums;

use yii2mod\enum\helpers\BaseEnum;

/**
 * Class GenderType
 *
 * @package yii2mod\settings\models\enumerables
 */
class GenderType extends BaseEnum
{
    // add as many genders as you need
    const MALE_TYPE = 'MALE';
    const FEMALE_TYPE = 'FEMALE';

    public static $list = [
        self::MALE_TYPE => 'Male',
        self::FEMALE_TYPE => 'Female',
    ];
}
```

Use the following methods to access your Enum:

- createByName() - Creates a new type instance using the name of a
  value.
- getValueByName() - Returns the constant key by value(label)
- createByValue() - Creates a new type instance using the value.
- listData() - Returns the associative array with constants values and
  labels
- getLabel()- Returns the constant label by key
- getConstantsByName() - Returns the list of constants (by name) for
  this type.
- getConstantsByValue() - Returns the list of constants (by
  value) for this type.
- isValidName() - Checks if a name is valid for
  this type. isValidValue() - Checks if a value is valid for this type.