# Command line Yii2 migration for enum

Tags: enums, yii2, command, migration

I am using to migrate in yii2 in command line

```
yii migrate/create create_post_table --fields="customer_id:integer,registered_from:enum('app','web'),created_at:datetime,updated_at:datetime"
```

which create migration files but while using

```
yii migrate
```

enum doesn't work.
 I want to migrate without editing manually in m161215_121914_create_post_table.php. What should i do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make field enum migration yii2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106804/how-to-make-field-enum-migration-yii2)

Comment: No i know that tricks which you want to say but i want to do migrate using command line without editing manually in m161215_121914_create_post_table.php int the above case.

Comment: Hm, ColumnSchemaBuilder class don't have type "enum" in categoryMap - so it's probably not implemented.

Answer (score 0):

```
public $tableName = 'sms_template';

public function up()
{
    $result = $this->db->createCommand('SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_name ="' . $this->tableName . '"')->queryAll();
    if ($result) {
        return true;
    }

    $tableOptions = null;
    if ($this->db->driverName === 'mysql') {
        $tableOptions = 'CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE=MyISAM';
    }

    $this->createTable(
        $this->tableName,
        [
            'id' => $this->integer(5)->unsigned()->notNull()->comment('模板id'),
            'name' => $this->string(32)->notNull()->defaultValue('0')->comment('模板名字')
        ],
        $tableOptions
    );
    $this->addPrimaryKey('id', $this->tableName, 'id');

    //处理枚举类型字段 enum
    $this->addColumn($this->tableName, 'status', "enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '模板状态 0=失败,1=成功'");
    $this->addColumn($this->tableName, 'is_delete', "enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '是否可删除 0=不可以 1=可以'");
}
```

Comment: Although yii2 migrate can not directly support enum but can be converted through the original sql way to create, but also to achieve the goal

Answer (score 0):

You could create ENUM in postgres like below

```
public function safeUp()
{
   $this->execute("CREATE TYPE statusEnum AS ENUM ('ACTIVE', 'INACTIVE')");

   $this->createTable('dummy_table', [
       "status0" => "statusEnum",
       "status1" => "statusEnum  default 'ACTIVE'",
       "status2" => $this->getDb()->getSchema()->createColumnSchemaBuilder("statusEnum  default 'ACTIVE'"),
   ];
}

public function safeDown()
{
    $this->execute('DROP TYPE statusEnum');
}
```